# Show all JIRA issues closed after its Internal Deadine date?

Tags: jira, jql

We have a custom field called `Internal Deadline` in our JIRA but how do I find all issues that has already been `Closed` but has surpassed its deadline?

```
{
  id: "customfield_6524",
  name: "Internal Deadline",
  custom: true,
  orderable: true,
  navigable: true,
  searchable: true,
  clauseNames: [
    "cf[6524]",
    "Internal Deadline"
  ],
  schema: {
    type: "date",
    custom: "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:datepicker",
    customId: 6524
  }
}
```

I have no problem in checking where we have missed the deadline `now()` but I want the historical data too but there is no possibility to chose my `Closed` status in the JQL:

[image]

Trying to put the `Resolved` date results in this error:

```
Date value 'Resolved' for field 'Internal Deadline' is invalid.
Valid formats include: 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'YYYY-MM-DD', or a period 
format e.g. '-5d', '4w 2d'.
```

Maybe JIRA has only been designed with the here-and-now date in scope? I had hoped I could monitor the "delivery track record".

Comment: I'm not sure fields can be rvalues. If all else fails, you can make a script with Groovy Runner: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download Script runner plugin (free), that provides some already implemented functions for JQL querying. Once you have it installed, you just can use this query:

```
issueFunction in dateCompare("","Internal Deadline < Resolved")
```

For further reference see the docs for `dateCompare` here, https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_datecompare